# How do I hook up my CSS grid table to an Array?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, frontend, ember-octane

I have a 5x5 grid set up on my .HBS.  I want to hold the state of my game somehow using ember.js OCTANE.  How do I do this, and what's the best way?  Please share ideas.  Do I need to create a model?  I'm new to Octane so please help.  So far, I've just created a grid component and I'm trying to use glimmer tracking with an array.

HBS:

```
    <table class="quantize" style="width: 80%">
        {{#each (range 0 5) as |row|}}
        <tr class="">
            {{#each (range 0 5) as |cell|}} 
                    <td
                     class="border border-dark"
                     style="width:10%">
                        {{cell}}                        
                    </td>           
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think keeping state on the component is the simplest, in cases when your original data is hard-coded and you don't need to get it from a server or save it to a server.

I recommend checking out the Octane Tutorial to learn these patterns in more depth. You can access it [here](https://emberjs.com/editions/octane/).

### Storing array state in an Octane component:

First, we put the array data into a tracked property, and write an action that can modify that data:

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { tracked } from '@glimmer/tracking';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  @tracked items = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  ];

  @action
  editItem(item) {
    this.items[0][0] = item // make some changes

    // The line below is important when working with tracked arrays and objects. Always "reset" the array whenever you make changes. This tells Ember to update what is rendered.
    this.items = this.items;
  }
}
```

We iterate over that 2D array using `each` helpers. We refer to the items as `this.items` since they are defined on "this component"

```
    <table class="quantize" style="width: 80%">
        {{#each this.items as |row|}}
        <tr class="">
            {{#each row as |cell|}} 
                    <td
                     class="border border-dark"
                     style="width:10%">
                        {{cell}}                        
                    </td>           
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
```

### Keeping state in the route's model

If you wanted to put the array data into the model hook of the route, you could do that too. However, model is mostly used when you are fetching data from an API. Pros are that Ember handles some async fetching and rendering for you, cons are that it's more complicated. An Octane component is only allowed to make changes to the data that it "owns." If changes need to be made to data that was passed in from a parent component or route, it has to be done by calling a function that was also passed in. This is referred to as "one way binding."

First we return the data from the model hook of a route:

```js
// routes/my-route.js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default class MyRoute extends Route {
  model() {
   return [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   ];
   // or return a fetch() request for that data
  }
}
```

```js
// controllers/my-route.js

import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class MyRouteController extends Controller {
  @action
  editItems(items) {
    this.model = items;
  }
}
```

We pass that model data and our editItems action to the component that displays the table:

```
<!-- templates/my-route.hbs -->
<MyComponent @items={{this.model}} @editItems={{action "editItems"}} />
```

In our component, we refer to the items as `@items` and not `this.items`. `@` is used when data comes from the outside, like a parent route or component.

```
<!-- my-component.hbs -->
    <table class="quantize" style="width: 80%">
        {{#each @items as |row|}}
        <tr class="">
            {{#each row as |cell|}} 
                    <td
                     class="border border-dark"
                     style="width:10%">
                        {{cell}}                        
                    </td>           
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
```

Then when you want to make changes to the array, you have to call the `editItems` function that was passed in. It's available as `this.args.editItems`. `this.args` are whatever was passed into the component from the parent.

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { action } from '@ember/object';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {

  @action
  buttonWasClicked(item) {
    this.args.editItems(item)
  }
}
```

Or, you could use the action passed in directly in your template, and hand it the item that you want to change.

```
<!-- my-component.hbs -->

<button {{on "click" (fn @editItems item)}}>edit item</button>
```

Comment: I like to do `this.items = [...this.items]` to make it look less like a no-op. No idea if there are performance implications. :/

Comment: @handlebears Thank you so much!  This works except when I update the state it doesn't effect the handlebars but just changes the state.  What I mean is I need a good way to change the #each row line to this.items or else I can't change the color of a square. I think I need something like {{#each this.testGrid[row] as |cell|}}

Comment: Update: Ok so I figured out how to do it using .slice